# Spring StoredProcedure

Tags: jdbc

Can we pass the output and input parameter to SQLParameter by index and not by name ?

```
    /* This code snippet explains data access thru CallableStatement by registering the output and input params by index. */ 

    Connection conn = getConnection();
    CallableStatement sp = conn.prepareCall("pkg_name.proc_name");
    sp.registerOutParameter(1, oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes.CURSOR);
    sp.registerOutParameter(2, oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes.NUMBER);
    ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) sp.getObject(2);
```

Here resultset can be fetched based on index.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can. [Java API doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#registerOutParameter%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) is your friend.

```
public void registerOutParameter(String parameterName,
                      int sqlType)
                      throws SQLException;
```

Comment: Sorry, i missed something here.

Comment: Sorry, i missed something here. I am trying to use spring api - StoredProcedure. While using this we have to pass in output and input parameters by typeName. Is there a way we can pass paramIndex instead of strong binding by name.

Comment: private class MyStoredProcedure extends StoredProcedure {
        
        private static final String SQL = "sysdate";

        public MyStoredProcedure(DataSource ds) {
            setDataSource(ds);
            setFunction(true);
            setSql(SQL);
            declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("date", Types.DATE));
            compile();
        }

        public Map execute() {
            // the 'sysdate' sproc has no input parameters, so an empty Map is supplied...
            return execute(new HashMap());
        }
    }